# Последовательность чисел с помощью CTE SQL

Tags: sql

Нужно сгенерировать последовательность из чисел 1-10 и 100 с помощью CTE. 1-10 генерируются рекурсивно, но не понимаю, как в тогда в конец добавить число 100:

```
WITH Sequence1 AS (SELECT 1 AS Number 
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT Number + 1 
                    FROM Sequence1
                    WHERE Number < 10)
SELECT Number FROM Sequence1;
```

Comment: 11 чисел всего? да при такой потребности - тупо статически, нет смысла огород городить с динамикой.

Answer (score 1):

Например, так

```
WITH Sequence1 AS (SELECT 1 AS Number 
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT Number + 1 
                    FROM Sequence1
                    WHERE Number < 10
                    )
,sequence2 as
(SELECT Number FROM Sequence1
 union all select 100
 )
 select * from sequence2;
```

Comment: Спасибо, а без sequence2 никак?

Comment: WITH Sequence1 AS (SELECT 1 AS Number 
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT Number + 1 
                    FROM Sequence1
                    WHERE Number < 100
                    )
 select * from sequence1 where number not between 11 and 99;